# what is memoir's version of the glossary \gls command?

Tags: memoir, glossaries

In this MWE the `\gls` command is not recognized, but I can's find memoir's version of it in memman.pdf - please help:

```
 \documentclass{memoir}

\makeglossary
\glossary{meter}{unit of lenght}

\begin{document}
Here I cite \gls{meter}. % undefined control sequence

\printglossary
\end{document}
```

Comment: None  -- you need the glossaries package

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `memoir` class does provide means for a `glossary`, using the `\glossary` command and displaying it with `\printglossary`, however, there's no `\gls` or related command that does display the glossary item inline, i.e. outside of the glossary itself.

I suggest to use the `glossaries` package and run the `makeglossaries` script after compilation (`pdflatex foo.tex ; makeglossaries foo ; pdflatex foo` again)

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossary
%\glossary{meter}{unit of lenght}

\newglossaryentry{meter}{name=meter,description={unit of length}}

\begin{document}
Here I cite \gls{meter}. % undefined control sequence

\printglossary
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `glossaries` package is particular useful in conjunction with `hyperref`, in my point of view.

Comment: That works, thanks, but it seems to make memoir's definition of `\glossary` completely worthless, right?

Comment: I have no other solution. `\glossary` is a `memoir` command, true. It's not always possible to mix anything out of the box

Comment: Of course, but it would then be better to remove such useless commands from the manual - it made me search for a \gls-like command, both in the manual and on the internet.

Comment: @WyboDekker: Well, the command is not useless, there's just a difference between `\glossary` as implemented by Peter Wilson (`memoir`) and the way Nicola Talbot (`glossaries) understands this.

Comment: @WyboDekker: Don't mix what you remember from a package with a class. I don't see why a class's macros should be removed because you get mixed up. Did you read and UNDERSTAND memoir's manual?

Comment: Maybe my problem is that I wanted to make my first glossary, with references to it in the text. As a memoir user it seemed logical to look in the manual and I found chapter 17.3. But I did not find a referencing command, like \gls. I now realize that a glossary can  be useful without a referencing mechanism. After all I think that a hint in the manual would be useful, saying that if one wants to make references to the glossary, one should use the glossaries package, not memoir's internal glossary macro's.

Comment: @WyboDekker: Maybe that's a way, yes. It's just a different views of concepts. I remember to have some `glossary` setup in the late 90s with a `glossary` C code, that was 'pretty' nice to do. The built -in version of `memoir` is much nicer to use as was the older version then, believe me

Comment: @WyboDekker `\glossary` is actually a kernel command. Its default definition is much the same as the default definition of `\index`. Both `memoir` and `glossaries` redefine `\glossary`, but `glossaries` hides the use of `\glossary` because the way it works requires a specific syntax within the argument of `\glossary`. Whereas `memoir` changes the syntax of `\glossary` so that it has two mandatory arguments (and some optional ones). This is just a slight evolution from the original kernel `\glossary` command, which can be used without `memoir` or `glossaries` in the same manner as `\index`.